# Read just a part of a big string

Tags: c#, string, stringreader

I have a large string to read and it's always different, but one word is always the same. The word is `MESSAGE`, so if my string reader comes across that word it has to write that whole string to disc. I did some code but it's not working, the if segment never triggers, what is wrong here?

```
string aLine;
StringReader strRead = new StringReader(str);
aLine = strRead.ReadLine();

if (aLine == "MESSAGE")
{
    //Write the whole file on disc
}
```

Comment: if(aLine.Contains("Message");

Comment: Is it always `MESSAGE` or can it also be `Message`? If so: `if(aLine.IndexOf("message", CultureInfo.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)...`

Comment: Yes it always MESSAGE, this is "hard-coded" in string, like a "safety word"

Comment: @CrBruno: you should also trim spaces, so if it's important that the word is at the beginning of the line it is  a good idea to use `Trim` first: `if(aLine.Trim().StartsWith("MESSAGE"))...` or just `if(aLine.Trim() == "MESSAGE")...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to work with [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
            string aLine;
            StringReader strRead = new StringReader(str);
            aLine = strRead.ReadLine();

            if (aLine.Contains("MESSAGE"))
            {

              //Write the whole file on disc

            }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Contains,

```
if(aLine.Contains("MESSAGE")
{
}
```

Comment: +1 to counter downvote (not sure why someone downvoted, you were actually the first to suggest using `Contains`).

Comment: true - I have seen this several times with a user answering here (will not say who) - I think the downvotes to get his answer up

Comment: @restless - rep farming - this is the No1 problem with this site

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (aLine.Contains("MESSAGE"))
```

You can also use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) but as index is not relevant here so better to use `Contains`.

```
if (aLine.IndexOf("MESSAGE") != -1)
```

If you need ignore case or Cultrue sensitivity then you IndexOf would provide you overloaded method for it, [String.IndexOf(string value,   StringComparison comparisonType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx)

```
if (aLine.IndexOf("MESSAGE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use `Contains`?

Comment: `Contains` returns a bool and cannot be compared to an int!

Comment: With `IndexOf` you can provide a `StringComparison`. That's not possible with (the non `char` version of) `Contains`.

Comment: @Corak ... and the problem *here* is what?

Comment: @Corak yeah, but the OP states `one word is always the same` so an exact comparison using `Contains` is all that's needed here.

Comment: @CarstenKönig - no problem, just an addition if for some reason culture invariance or case insensitivity might play a role (now or in the future).

Comment: Oh, and as @DanielKelley mentioned, `Contains` calls `IndexOf` internally. But yes, using `Contains` better conveys the intention. And it's not as if one way is totally wrong. Good to know both.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.string.indexof.aspx). In that case you could use the following:

```
if (aLine.IndexOf("MESSAGE") > -1)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Same comment from @Adil's answer, wouldn't it be easier to use `Contains`?

Comment: I wasn't aware (until just now) that `Contains` calls `IndexOf`.

Comment: -1 because it's `> -1` and because it's only a good idea if you want to compare insensitively: `aLine.IndexOf("MESSAGE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter is right: this one is wrong if you have something like `aLine = "MESSAGE..."`

Comment: I've fixed the return check. As for casing - as the OP explicitly used "MESSAGE" I assumed it was case insensitive. The link to the MSDN docs clearly show the overloads available to the method that would allow case insensitive checks.